# Can't click on the table created with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, html-table, click, mouseevent

I'm creating a table with images using jQuery. My js code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var korpusArray = new Array();
    $.getJSON("file.js", function(data) {
        var korpusId;
        var korpusChooseTable = "<table id='TableKorpusGaleria'><tbody><tr>";
        $.each(data, function(i, value) {
            korpusArray.push(value.text);
            strRemove = value.filename.replace("korpus/", "");
            korpusChooseTable += '<td><p>'+value.title+'</p><p style="display:none;">'+value.id+'</p></br><img src="/korpus/thumbs/phoca_thumb_s_'+strRemove+'"></td>';
        });
        korpusChooseTable += '</tr></tbody></table>'; 
        $("#korpusChoose").html(korpusChooseTable);
        console.log(korpusArray.length);
        console.log(data.length);
    });
    // after this I wanna click on table cell and do some function but
    // it doesnt work. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?
    $("#korpusChoose #TableKorpusGaleria tbody td").click(function() {
        alert();
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the generated table's html look like?

Comment: Incidently, some browsers dislike `alert()`, stick to `alert(1)` or better `console.log` (provided your browser supports this).

Comment: Yes, I tried, and with 
$("#korpusChoose table tbody td").click(function(){
  alert();
  });

Comment: alert('helo'); doesnt work too / chrome

Comment: <table> is good formatted, shouldnt be problem with them

Comment: <div id="korpusChoose"><table id="TableKorpusGaleria"><tbody><tr><td><p>korpus1 edited</p><p style="display:none;">29</p><br><img src="/korpus/thumbs/phoca_thumb_s_korpus1.png"></td></tr></tbody></table></div> (I remowed the full link of the img)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegation for dynamically created items - if the element does not exist at the time of binding... which is usually at dom ready - then no event handlers will be attached

jQuery 1.7 and up http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("#korpusChoose ").on('click','#TableKorpusGaleria tbody td',function(){
       alert();       
});
```

or jQuery 1.6 down to jQuery 1.4.3 http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$("#korpusChoose ").delegate('#TableKorpusGaleria tbody td','click',function(){
       alert();       
});
```

> > Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:
> >
> > $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
> >
> > $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
> >
> > $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

Another way would be to add right after you add it to the dom

```
$("#korpusChoose").html(korpusChooseTable);
```

then right after

```
$("#korpusChoose #TableKorpusGaleria tbody td").click(function(){
     alert();
});
```

Though the latter is less efficient since you would be binding an event handler to every td element in the table - using delegation you only bind it to a parent element which exists in the dom and will handle the event when it bubbles up

Comment: Your 1.6 and below code is wrong.  `on` didn't exist.  Think you meant `delegate`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yeah you're correct.. that is what I meant - whoops

Comment: $("#korpusChoose ").on('click','#TableKorpusGaleria tbody td',function(){
       alert();       
}); // it WORKS!! ...

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the table is created dynamically, you will need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), using jquery's `on`.  This will allow you to attach a handler before the element exists.

```
$("#korpusChoose #TableKorpusGaleria tbody td").click(function(e){
```

would instead be

```
$("container").on("focus", "#korpusChoose #TableKorpusGaleria tbody td",function(e){
```

where `container` is a selector for some static ancestor element which is not dynamically loaded.  If no such container exists, `document` can be used, though this is to be avoided where possible.

Comment: On a related note which isn't directly relevant to the question; you can exclude the `#korpusChoose` bit of the selector as the 2nd `id` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Because the table is generated dynamically you could use:

```
$('#mytable').live('click', function() {
    // Click event handler action here...
});
```

Using the live() method to bind event handlers they will also be triggered on elements created dynamically by AJAX calls or similar.

**Update:** Since .live() is deprecated since JQuery 1.7, thanks to Andrew, consider using .on() for event delegation.

Comment: `live` is deprecated in favour of `on` since jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `$("table").live("click",function(){
});` Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. Jquery click only binds the click event for present elements in the document .

http://jsfiddle.net/wFcpP/3/

Comment: `live` is deprecated in favor of `on` as of 1.7.  Even in versions prior to 1.7, `delegate` should be used in place of `live` where possible.