# Using Jquery to change class on dynamic generated element

Tags: jquery

I have a script that dynamically generates a grid by using a table.

```
//createGrid(height, width);
createGrid(1, 2);
//one row with 2 cols
```

Which creates this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need an onclick event for the td tags that add/changes their class. I've tried a few solutions to no avail. Any ideas? I'm not great at Jquery.

Comment: i doubt you tried anything.. if you typed your question into google, you would have the answer right away -> [see](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+dynamically+created+elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't click on the table created with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496022/cant-click-on-the-table-created-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

For dynamically-generated elements, events should be delegated, from one of static parents of the element or `document` object, you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td', function(){
   $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jquery function for binding the dynamically generated item for event delegation, It binds the existing elements with event and It will also bind element which are added dynamically. `$('td').click(function(){});` will only bind the existing element but not the added dynamically after he binding.

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function(){
     alert("clicked");
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You can change document with some parent element selector.

Comment: I'd add in why this differs from `$('td').click()`.

Comment: I did as he requires for dynamically generated elements

Comment: I mean, explain how this is different and why you would use this instead of the regular `.click()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `find`, `live` and `toggleClass`

```
$("table").find("td").live("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});​
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6A3U/)

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7 `live` method is deprecated.